# how to fix multi confirm windows on chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to use confirm option. but for some reason the confirm opens multi times 12-15. even if i click accept once.

how can i fix it to open only once

## popup.js

```
function injectTheScript() {
    // if you don't specify a tab id, executeScript defaults to active tab in current window
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({file:'content_script.js', allFrames:true});
    // by adding allFrames:true, the code will be run in all the iframes of the webpage, not only the top context
}

document.getElementById('B7').addEventListener('click',injectTheScript);
```

## content_script

```
 if(confirm("Are you Sure?")){
var theButton = document.querySelector('.sidebarShowButton');  //a shorter way to select the first element of a class
if (theButton) {
    // if the element is present in this context, click on it.
    theButton.click();
}
 }

var addnote = document.querySelector('.d-icon-note_pencil');
if (addnote) {
    // if the element is present in this context, click on it.
    addnote.click();
}
```

Comment: Try setting `allFrames:false`.

Comment: i have to use allFrames:true beause its a website with alot of frames. but i want the confirm to be once becuse i want my function to wotk once.

Comment: Well, your code calls confirm() in each iframe so naturally you see multiple dialogs. The solution depends on how the site is organized. If theButton and addnote are present only in one iframe then it's trivial to solve. Otherwise you'll have to use cross-frame messaging via window.top.postMessage to ask the content script of the main page to allow the confirm dialog.

Comment: @wOxxOm
the function click on buttons in i frame and then click on buttons in the main page so i think i need to use the window.top.postMessage, but how can use it on my code?

i just want it to ask me if i want to run the function.

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs in each iframe so naturally you see multiple confirm dialogs.

If theButton and addnote are present only in one iframe then it's trivial to solve:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebarShowButton, .d-icon-note_pencil');
if (buttons.length && confirm('Are you sure?')) {
  buttons.forEach(btn => btn.click());
}
```

Otherwise you'll have to use cross-frame messaging via window.top.postMessage to ask the content script of the main page to allow the confirm dialog:

```
const ID = chrome.runtime.id;

if (window === top) {
  let confirmed = null;
  window.addEventListener('message', event => {
    switch (event.data) {
      case ID + ':check':
        event.source.postMessage(ID + ':' + confirmed, '*');
        break;
      case ID + ':set-true':
      case ID + ':set-false':
        confirmed = ID.endsWith('true');
        break;
    }
  });
}

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebarShowButton, .d-icon-note_pencil');
if (buttons.length) {
  getConfirmStatus().then(confirmed => {
    if (confirmed) {
      buttons.forEach(btn => btn.click());
    }
  });
}

function getConfirmStatus() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    window.addEventListener('message', event => {
      let status;
      switch (event.data) {
        case ID + ':true':
        case ID + ':false':
          status = event.data.endsWith('true');
          break;
        case ID + ':null':
          status = confirm('Are you sure?');
          window.top.postMessage(ID + ':set-' + status, '*');
          break;
        default:
          return;
      }
      resolve(status);
    }, {once: true});
    window.top.postMessage(ID + ':check', '*');
  })
}
```

Comment: the first code you gave me open ups 2 confirm box, but stiil not 1.

the second one is same ,2 times it asks for yes or no.

i have 3 commands on the frame and the rest is in the mainpage.

there is no option just to ask the user if he want to run the all fucntion only once?

Comment: 1) Try the new version. 2) There's no magic way to display the confirm() only once per tab.

Comment: not looking for magic, I have a website with only 1 frame and a mainpage.
i want it to click on button in the frame and then do some click on the mainpage.

i dont think its hard.

its just that everty time i get 12-15 boxes when i use the confirm or window.prompt() do the same.

right now the code you gave me, showing me the box 2 times so its a progress but not compelte so thank you.

i hope you can help me with other solutions meaby.

Comment: by the way if i do :" allFrames:false"
it work well but i dont have access to the frames, how can click on a button with a specifec frame or area in the page? and not in the mainpage ?

Comment: I was only demonstrating the principle of a solution and now it's up to you to debug it.

Comment: ok thank you, i will start working on that.
i will post here if i have solution.